# Conditional rounded corners on stacked bar chart

Tags: zingchart

I have a chart with stacked bars A and B

A is on top of B and A have top corners rounded but not B.

But I want B having rounded top corners when A = 0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the ZingChart Stacked Bar [chart token](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/elements/tokens#tokens-list) “%scale-value-value” (or “%vv”) for this.  It’s the [sum value of the stacked node and all nodes stacked below it](https://app.zingsoft.com/view/EXDU3Q0N).
Using a [rule](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/elements/rules), compare this sum value to the “%stack-total” (or “%total”) to determine if the node is the top of the stack, then add your border radius:

```
“rules”: [
   {
    “rule”: “%vv == %stack-total”,
    “borderRadiusTopLeft”: “10rem”,
    “borderRadiusTopRight”: “10rem”
   }
 ]
```

Put that rule in your “plot” object and you should be fine.
[I made a demo in the ZingChart studio if you want to check it out.](https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/view/EGAOL00C)

Comment: Didn't notice the `%scale-value-value` token. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (more or less flexible, depending on the setup) is to use (%node-value)(PLOTINDEX) locator to check for the value of the node "below"

```
"rules":[
    {
        "rule":"(%node-value)(2) === 0",
        "borderRadiusTopLeft":"10rem",
        "borderRadiusTopRight":"10rem"
    }
]
```

This basically says: if the value of the corresponding node of the 3rd plot (plot index is 2) is zero, then round the borders.

See: https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/view/ZJ1XMRK3